# Widget translation using WPML and Widget Logic Plugin

Tags: translation, language-translation, wpml

I have an unexpected issue with my wordpress site. I am running 3 languages on my site: English, Bahasa Malay and Simplified Chinese. And when I am trying to add Malay translated widget using this code `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'bm'` than it can not show me that widget in frontend. Kindly help me to getting out on it please. This is my website URL please have a look http://www.cerdasjaya.com/

Regards,
Yousuf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I just released a plugin which helps you select which widget you want to show for a language.

You might want to take a look: [WPML Widgets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpml-widgets)